# Running dict.clear but the dictionary still prints with items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to run option 11, to clear my dictionary, but when I run the clear option (11), and then the view all items option (4), it prints the same dictionary as above without clearing it.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work as I am stuck?

```
basketball_scores = {'Luke' : 18, 'Nick' : 7, 'Ben': 10, 'Dylan' : 87, 'Liam' : 34, 'Jake' : 69,
                     'Salmon' : 2, 'Ashley' : 120, 'Kirkus' : 1, 'Parlas' : -9}

def menu():
    print('''
=====Player Points Dictionary=====
    1. Add a player.
    2. Delete a player.
    3. Modify a player's points.
    4. View all items.
    5. Get a player's statistic.
    6. View all player's.
    7. View all point statistics.
    8. Sort dictionary by player name.
    9. Sort dictionary by point statistic.
    10. Player lucky dip.
    11. Clear the dictionary.
    12. Exit.
==================================
''')

def main():
    menu()
    option = int(input('Which option would you like to run? '))
    print()

    while option not in range(1, 11):
        option = int(input('Which option would you like to run? '))
        print()

    if option in range(1, 11):
        if option == 1:
            name = str(input("What is the player's name? "))
            points = int(input('How many points has {0} scored? '.format(name)))
            basketball_scores[name] = points
        elif option == 2:
            name = str(input('Which player would you like to delete? '))
            del basketball_scores[name]
        elif option == 3:
            name = str(input("Which player's points would you like to change? "))
            points = int(input('How many points has {0} scored? '.format(name)))
            basketball_scores[name] = points
        elif option == 4:
            print(dict.items(basketball_scores))
        elif option == 5:
            name = str(input("Which player's points would you like? "))
            print('{0} has scored {1} points.'.format(name, basketball_scores.get(name)))
        elif option == 6:
            print(dict.keys(basketball_scores))
        elif option == 7:
            print(dict.values(basketball_scores))
        elif option == 8:
            # A dictionary has absolutely no order, the sorted dictionary is really an array with lists inside of it
            # t[0] is the first item in the dictionary, so a player name. Therefore it will sort by name/string
            sortedByNameDict = sorted(basketball_scores.items(), key = lambda t: t[0])
            print(sortedByNameDict)
        elif option == 9:
            # t[1] is the second item in the dictionary, so a player's points. Therefore it will sort by points/integer.
            sortedByPointsDict = sorted(basketball_scores.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])
            # dictionary.reverse simply reverses the list so that it is in descending points order (largest to smallest)
            sortedByPointsDict.reverse()
            print(sortedByPointsDict)
        elif option == 10:
            print(dict.popitem(basketball_scores))
        elif option == 11:
            dict.clear(basketball_scores)
        elif option == 12:
            quit

main()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `dict....` instead of calling the methods directly on the `basketball_scores` dict? Also range is half-open so you never reach 11

Comment: Also if your wile loop breaks then option has to be in the range so your if is redundant.

Comment: x in range(a,b) means a<=x<b . So, when you enter 11, the program do not go inside if option. So, make it option in range(1,12)

Answer (score 1):

`range(1, 11)` doesn't include 11, so you're just skipping that input. I recommend using a chained comparison:

```
1 <= option <= 11
```

rather than `in range(...)`. It makes the behavior on the bounds more explicit (and allows you to specify the behavior), it works better on Python 2, and it works for floats.